# Getting attribute of type postgres

Tags: postgresql

lets say I create a type like this:

```
CREATE TYPE books AS (
  book_id NUMERIC
, row_num NUMERIC
);
```

I want to write a query that returns me the attributes (book_id, row_num) of books.

I am not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT array_agg(a.attname) 
  FROM   pg_class c JOIN pg_attribute a 
         ON c.oid = a.attrelid
WHERE  c.relname = 'books';
```

Result

```
     array_agg
-------------------
 {book_id,row_num}
(1 row)
```

Comment: @dgamma3 : You're welcome. Please check. I've simplified the query.